# Why am I getting a NoNodeAvailableException with elastic search?

Tags: scala, playframework, elasticsearch

I'm a tester and fairly new to both play and scala. I have some source code to test, which I've managed to compile and have installed elastic search, which is being used as my data source. I'm getting an error when I try to run the code:

```
[NoNodeAvailableException: No node available]
```

I've seen other threads on this but they all refer to checking the elastic search nodes are configured in `application.conf`. However, the app I'm testing has no such file. Is there anywhere else the node could be configured? I'm at a loss to where the elasticsearch node is defined. I have elasticsearch 1.4.1 installed.

Any help would be much appreciated, I have exhausted all avenues within my current knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to tell Play where (IP and port) of your ElasticSearch instance. This is typically done in the `application.conf`.

Here are a few things you can try:

1. Have you looked inside the `conf` directory for `application.conf` ?
2. If you don't find it there, try looking at the stacktrace of your exception and see the source file where the exception is coming for. Inside the source file you will see how the IP/port is set for ElasticSearch.